# Can I use errors as conditions for if..else statement in Python? If yes, how?

Tags: python

What I am planning is when the user inputs something that results to an error (in my code, is the eval() which will cause the error in the input), it loops back.

```
while True:
  x = input('Enter price: ')
  y = eval(x)
  if y == #error condition
    print('Error! Please try again.')
    continue
  else:
    print(y)
    break
```

The output should be:

```
Enter price: +
Error! Please try again.
Enter price: 1+
Error! Please try again.
Enter price: 1+1
2
```

Is it possible? I am using Python 3.4 btw.

Comment: Do you have to use `if.. else`, if not, you can use [try .. except](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Why use `eval` on user input? I assume it's a small experiment, but otherwise it seems a bad idea.

Comment: @SSC I haven't come across try.. except until now. I have no idea. haha

@Evert I am using it for the "calculator" part of our project, which does the basic math. So far, `eval` works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `try ... except` construct. It will catch Exceptions:

```
while True:
    x = input('Enter price: ')
    try:
        y = eval(x)
    except Exception:
        print('Error! Please try again.')
        continue

    print(y)
    break
```